# Problema com o meu jogo Pedra, Papel e Tesoura

Tags: javascript, comparação

Estou com um problema na função `maquina()`, a função não esta conseguindo executar nenhuma ação, acho que a função não esta recebendo o valor da variável `jgdJogador`.

```
var comecar = false, i = 1;
if (i === 1){
    alert('Bem vindo ao Pedra, Papel e Tesoura!')
    var decisao = prompt('Aperte 1 para comecar a jogar ');
    if(decisao === '1'){
        main();
    }
}

// Jogadas Maquina
function maquina(jogada){

    var jgdMaquina = ['Pedra', 'Papel', 'Tesoura'];
    var numero =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 0)) + 0;

    if (jgdMaquina[numero] == 0 && jogada == '1') {
        alert('maquina jogou pedra');
        alert('empate');
    }

    if (jgdMaquina[numero] == 0 && jogada == '2') {
        alert('maquina jogou pedra');
        alert('voce ganhou');
    }

    if (jgdMaquina[numero] == 0 && jogada == '3') {
        alert('maquina jogou pedra');
        alert('voce perdeu');
    }

    if (jgdMaquina[numero] == 1 && jogada == '1') {
        alert('maquina jogou papel');
        alert('voce perdeu');
    }

    if (jgdMaquina[numero] == 1 && jogada == '2') {
        alert('maquina jogou papel');
        alert('empate');
    }

    if (jgdMaquina[numero] == 1 && jogada == '3') {
        alert('maquina jogou papel');
        alert('voce ganhou');
    }

    if (jgdMaquina[numero] == 2 && jogada == '1') {
        alert('maquina jogou tesoura');
        alert('voce ganhou');
    }

    if (jgdMaquina[numero] == 2 && jogada == '2') {
        alert('maquina jogou tesoura');
        alert('voce perdeu');
    }

    if (jgdMaquina[numero] == 2 && jogada == '3') {
        alert('maquina jogou tesoura');
        alert('empate');
    }

}

// Funcao principal
function main (){
    alert('Escolha a sua jogada: ');
    var jgdJogador = prompt(`
                            1 - Pedra
                            2 - Papel
                            3 - Tesoura
                            `);
    if (jgdJogador == '1' || jgdJogador == '2' || jgdJogador == '3'){
        maquina(jgdJogador);
    }
}
```

Comment: `jgdMaquina[numero]` retorna *pedra*, *papel* ou *tesoura* e não um valor numérico, logo `jgdMaquina[numero] == 0`, `jgdMaquina[numero] == 1` e `jgdMaquina[numero] == 2` sempre serão inválidos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O maior problema é que criou um *array* sem necessidade e está comparando o elemento dele que é um texto com um número, não faz sentido, basta comparar o número sorteado com o número desejado naquela iteração.

Existiam outras coisas sem necessidade que eu tirei (não resolvi os problemas menos importantes que não impedem o funcionamento normal):

```js
function maquina(jogada) {
    var numero =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if (numero == 0 && jogada == '1') {
        alert('maquina jogou pedra');
        alert('empate');
    }
    if (numero == 0 && jogada == '2') {
        alert('maquina jogou pedra');
        alert('voce ganhou');
    }
    if (numero == 0 && jogada == '3') {
        alert('maquina jogou pedra');
        alert('voce perdeu');
    }
    if (numero == 1 && jogada == '1') {
        alert('maquina jogou papel');
        alert('voce perdeu');
    }
    if (numero == 1 && jogada == '2') {
        alert('maquina jogou papel');
        alert('empate');
    }
    if (numero == 1 && jogada == '3') {
        alert('maquina jogou papel');
        alert('voce ganhou');
    }
    if (numero == 2 && jogada == '1') {
        alert('maquina jogou tesoura');
        alert('voce ganhou');
    }
    if (numero == 2 && jogada == '2') {
        alert('maquina jogou tesoura');
        alert('voce perdeu');
    }
    if (numero == 2 && jogada == '3') {
        alert('maquina jogou tesoura');
        alert('empate');
    }
}

alert('Bem vindo ao Pedra, Papel e Tesoura!')
if (prompt('Aperte 1 para comecar a jogar ') === '1') {
    alert('Escolha a sua jogada: ');
    var jgdJogador = prompt(`
                            1 - Pedra
                            2 - Papel
                            3 - Tesoura
                            `);
    if (jgdJogador === '1' || jgdJogador === '2' || jgdJogador === '3') maquina(jgdJogador);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/ComparingRandom.js).